# How to check if the contents of two columns from different tables are identical?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables in my SQL database. I want to check if the `Specifier` columns have the exact same data in the exact same order.

**OK case**, since both tables have the same data in the same order in the `Specifier` column:

```
-- Table1:
RowID   Specifier
187     1         
188     1         
189     2         

-- Table2:
RowID   Specifier
181     1         
182     1         
183     2
```

**ERROR case**, since the data is different:

```
-- Table1:
RowID   Specifier
187     1         
188     2         
189     3         

-- Table2:
RowID   Specifier
181     1         
182     2         
183     2
```

**ERROR case**, since the data is in different order:

```
-- Table1:
RowID   Specifier
187     1         
188     1         
189     2         

-- Table2:
RowID   Specifier
181     1         
182     2         
183     1
```

**ERROR case**, since different amount of data:

```
-- Table1:
RowID   Specifier
187     1         
188     1         
189     2         

-- Table2:
RowID   Specifier
181     1         
182     1         
183     2
184     1
```

I've written the following query, which almost works, and gives correctly an error if one table has a value the other doesn't, but it will incorrectly give no error if only the order is incorect:

```
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT Specifier FROM Table1 EXCEPT SELECT Specifier FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Specifier FROM Table2 EXCEPT SELECT Specifier FROM Table1)
BEGIN
    THROW 99999, 'Mismatching Specifiers between the two tables', 1;
END;
```

Comment: do the rowid also match or can same  Specifier has different rowid?

Comment: Do a full outer join.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No, the `RowID`s are completely irrelevant

Comment: The `rowid`s aren't irrelevant, they just don't match. You need to use them in `ORDER BY` clauses if you want to enforce row order rules.

Comment: @EricBrandt Ahh, ok.

Comment: @ruohola, even better the way Gordon implemented it in row numbers. Which is zero percent surprising. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `full join` and `row_number()`.  The following gets the exceptions:

```
select *
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by rowid) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by rowid) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum and t1.specifier = t2.specifier
where t1.seqnum is null or t2.seqnum is null;
```

If you simply want a flag:

```
select (case when count(*) > 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by rowid) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by rowid) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum and t1.specifier = t2.specifier
where t1.seqnum is null or t2.seqnum is null;
```

If you care about performance, using the first query with `exists` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it might be easier with

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowID) AS RN,
                        Specifier
                 FROM Table1) T1
                FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowID) AS RN,
                                        Specifier
                                 FROM Table2) T2 ON T1.RN = T2.RN
                                                AND T1.Specifier = T2.Specifier
           HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.RN IS NULL OR T2.RN IS NULL THEN 1 END) >= 1) ...
```

Comment: This seems to falsely compare also the `RowID` columns. They are completely irrelevant here.

Comment: If `RowID` is *"completely irrelevant"* then how do you define the order the values of `Specifier`, @ruohola ? Why include `RowID` in your question if it's not related the the problem?

Comment: I mean that they shouldn't be compared at all.

Comment: As you can see, your says that "something is different" if only the `RowID`s are: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f32f75948d5884eb71bc224bb533831

Comment: Yes, @ruohola, bceause something *is* different. The value of `RowID`.

Comment: Changed to create a new `RowID`, @ruohola . Thus results in a similar solution to Gordon's.